# Linux/C - Trying to use fstat() to pull i-node number of a file. Getting incorrect output

Tags: c, linux, file, filesystems

```
struct stat fileStats;
FILE *fd;
int not_used;

fd = fopen(temp_full_path, "r");
not_used = fstat(temp_full_path, &fileStats);
//printf("\n\n%d\n\n", atoi(inum));
printf("\n\nTest I-node num: %d\n\n", fileStats.st_ino);
if((atoi(inum) == fileStats.st_ino))
{
         printf("%s\n", temp_full_path);
}
fclose(fd);
```

I have tried the current implementation which is using the file path as an input to the fstat function. I have also tried using the fd file pointer, opening the input file, and then using fd as the input to fstat. Neither works. I get a wildly different output than the number I get from using the linux command: stat "filepath"

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would agree with the first point regarding the not_used variable but for this assignment, that error check is not necessary. I will try using the stat function in place of fstat and see if that works.

Comment: Switching to the stat function rather than fstat solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Note that you're passing a string (`temp_full_path`) to `fstat()` instead of the file descriptor which `fstat()` expects.  Your compiler should be shrieking at you about this.  If you check that `fd` (a `FILE *`, not a file descriptor — use `fp` for file streams and `fd` for file descriptors) is non-null, then you can use `fileno(fd)` as the first argument to `fstat()`.  You must test the return value from `fopen()`.  You should check the result from `fstat()`, though it is unlikely to fail if the `fopen()` succeeded.

Comment: The inode number (`ino_t`) might be too big to fit in an `int`.  Sadly, there isn't a standard notation to identify how to print `ino_t`.  Given that, use `%lld` and cast the value to `(long long)`, or `%llu` and cast to `(unsigned long long)`.  Or using `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t` from `<stdint.h>` and `%jd` or `%ju` and cast to the appropriate type.